# What does "Kill 50 enemies while on fire" mean?

Tags: luftrausers

A mission for the random armor selection is to "Kill 50 enemies while on fire". I take it to mean that I should kill 50 enemies in total "at very low health", but getting the counter to increase is very hit and miss.

- What does "on fire" mean?
- Is the counter reset each round?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty self explanatory :P

Comment: @Robotnik, it certainly looks that way, but it's obviously not the case. See the answer below.

Comment: I figured as much, I was just joking around :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Q:** What does "on fire" mean?
**A:** When your plane is damaged to a certain extent it starts to smoke, this is what's classed as "on fire".

**Q:** Is the counter reset each round?
**A:** No the counter is not reset.

What this objective fails to mention is that you have to kill your enemies by **ramming** into them. This is not at all clear and so leads to confusion.